# Creating directory if directory exists

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I have the following directory:

*\\192.168.255.86\Add-in\Requests\MyFolder1*

If this directory exists (there is already a folder on the specified path) I need to create the following:

*\\192.168.255.86\Add-in\Requests\MyFolder1 (1)*

If directory still exists I need to create another directory:

*\\192.168.255.86\Add-in\Requests\MyFolder1 (2)*

and so on.
I did it using while-loop in the following method:

```
public static string CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            return path;
        }
        int i = 1;
        while (Directory.Exists(path + $" ({i})"))
        {
            i++;
        }
        path += $" ({i})";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        return path;
    }
```

How to make it using recursion?

Comment: Have you attempted using recursion? Does the while loop work?

Comment: Recursion is easy. Understanding how it suppose to work, either from your explanation or the code - is not. What *"If directory still exists"* suppose to mean?

Comment: @Cal-cium while-loop works good. I try to use recursion but it's not working

Comment: @Sinatr This means that there is already a folder on the specified path, edit

Comment: From what I see you don't need recursion. You aren't *diving deeper*, it's always same level. Recursion will adds overhead (stack operation and memory).

Comment: I agree with @Sinatr. The while-loop will do the job just fine, no need for recursion for your requirements at all. No point using recursion just for the sake of using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need recursion here. All you want is create new directory with next available name (by adding number).

A slightly refactored method can looks like this:

```
public string NextDirectory(string path)
{
    var dir = path;
    int n = 1;
    while (Directory.Exists(dir))
        dir = $"{path} ({n++})";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    return dir;
}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution to the issue. Recursion is not necessary to resolve this problem.

Comment: My answer was posted hours before this, actually answered the question on how to do this with recursion, and included advice not to do so along with a solution that this was copy-pasted from but actually separated the two concerns of getting the unique path name and creating it. Yet this is the accepted answer? Seems fair.

Comment: @SteveHarris, looking at timeline ([yours](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48909147/timeline) and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48909351/timeline)) you post answer 10 min earlier, 5 min after my comment which I decide to turn into the answer and thus need some time to produce errorless code in VS. I didn't copy/pasted anything, I didn't even read your answer until now and yes, you are right, code looks very similar (the difference can be done on purpose to hide plagiarism). All I can give you an upvote and my word, I didn't steal anything from you.

Comment: @SteveHarris, if you feel what you must do something about it, then you can post question on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Tbh, I don't know how to resolve this situation, I've never before was blamed in plagiarism, no idea how to prove I am not guilty.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using recursion, this should be nice and elegant:

```
    public static string CreateDirectory(string path, int suffix = 0)
    {
        string directoryPath = DirectoryPath(path, suffix);
        if (!CreateDirectory(directoryPath))
            return CreateDirectory(path, i + 1);
        return directoryPath;
    }

    private static bool CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
            return false;

        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        return true;
    }

    private static string DirectoryPath(string path, int suffix)
    {
        return $"{path}{(suffix > 0 ? $" ({suffix})" : string.Empty)}";
    }
```

But if you already have 'MyFolder1 (214)' your call stack might be immense!

Maybe this is a slightly neater way to do the while loop (but essentially the same):

```
    public static string CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        string createPath = GetUniquePath(path);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(createPath);
        return createPath;
    }
    private static string GetUniquePath(string path)
    {
        string result = path;
        int i = 1;
        while (Directory.Exists(result))
            result = $"{path} ({i++})";
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  public static string CreateDirectory(string path, int i)
    {
        if (i>0)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(path + $" ({i})"))
                return CreateDirectory(path,++i);
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path + $" ({i})"));
                return path + $" ({i})";
            }
        }
        else
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                return path;
            }
            else
                return CreateDirectory(path,1);    
    }
```